# Trying out Spring 3 MVC, Getting a page error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to configure spring 3 MVC, here is what I did so far:

I added all the spring 3.0 libraries to my netbeans project.

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebApplication1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebApplication1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

Next I created a WebAppliation1-servlet.xml, also in my /web-inf folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 - DispatcherServlet application context for PetClinic's web tier.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

 <!--
  - The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation.
 -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.Hi"/>

 <!--
  - The form-based controllers within this application provide @RequestMapping
  - annotations at the type level for path mapping URLs and @RequestMapping
  - at the method level for request type mappings (e.g., GET and POST).
  - In contrast, ClinicController - which is not form-based - provides
  - @RequestMapping only at the method level for path mapping URLs.
  -
  - DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is driven by these annotations and is
  - enabled by default with Java 5+.
 -->



 <!--
  - This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical
  - view names for error views. The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet
  - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet container: this will happen
  - here with all other types of exceptions.
 -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
   <props>
    <prop key="org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound">pageNotFound</prop>
    <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
    <prop key="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>


 <!--
  - The BeanNameViewResolver is used to pick up the visits view name (below).
  - It has the order property set to 2, which means that this will
  - be the first view resolver to be used after the delegating content
  - negotiating view resolver.
  -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="1"/>
 <!--

  - This bean configures the 'prefix' and 'suffix' properties of
  - InternalResourceViewResolver, which resolves logical view names
  - returned by Controllers. For example, a logical view name of "vets"
  - will be mapped to "/WEB-INF/jsp/vets.jsp".
 -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
   p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>



</beans>
```

I then created a simple welcome.jsp in the folder /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

I then created a package:

org.springframework.Hi

And I created a TestController.java file:

package org.springframework.Hi;

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcomeHandler(){
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

I wanted this to work w/o any file extensions, so I don't have to end my urls with xxx.htm etc.

So when I run the netbeans project I get the error:

> ```
> type Status report
>
> message Servlet WebApplication1 is not available
>
> description The requested resource (Servlet WebApplication1 is not
> ```
>
> available) is not available.

What exactly am I missing here?

**Tomcat logs**

Thanks for the feedback

**My tomcat logs show this:**

```
SEVERE: Servlet /WebApplication1 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
```

Comment: Application logs? catalina.out?

Comment: Logs helped, see revised answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm asuming that error message you quoted was the error message the browser sees when it tries to access the application. This is because it didn't deploy properly.

You need to look through the web server startup logs, that will give you much more information as to why it didn't deploy.

**edit:** OK, that helps a lot... you need to add [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) to your classpath.

Comment: @skaffman I found the log files (learned something new today), it seems it can't find a class.

Comment: Actually I had to add download and add the apache commons logging library to my project.  Where exactly is it being referenced? I guess spring mvc uses it as by default?  (the page works, thanks!)

Comment: spring contains commons-logging.jar it self but I copy commons-logging-1.0.4.jar from another project.

Answer (score 0):

I used to encounter a similar problem... except it happened only when I try to run the Spring Web MVC app via the STS IDE (version 2.3.2). However, if I packaged as a WAR and deployed it to a running instance of tcServer or even Tomcat, the app worked just fine.

I ended up adding commons-logging and some other JARs to the server's launch configuration in STS IDE, in the User Entries section under the Classpath tab. This solved my problem. Why some JARs don't get added to the Java EE module dependency while running within STS, I don't still understand.

Hope this helps.